# Java Thumbnailator Library: IIOException occurred : Error reading PNG metadata

Tags: java, exception, base64, metadata

I use [this](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) open-open source library for creating thumbnails of images. My task is to convert File to Base64 String and then send this String as request parameter to REST Service. I convert file to Base64 String in client side by using this function:

```
public String convertToBase64(File file) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(bytes);
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "UTF-8");
}
```

Then i retrieve this encodedString and send this String as request parameter to REST Service.

In REST Service i decode this String by using this function:

```
    public static void uploadBase64Image(String file, String filename) throws Exception {
    filename = filename.replaceAll(" ", "_");
    byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary
            (file.replaceFirst("data:image/jpg;base64,", "")
                    .replaceFirst("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "")
                    .replaceFirst("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("base64", filename);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(tempFile, data);

    FileEntity fe = FileEntity.processAndCompressFile(tempFile, "pic");
    fe.save();
    renderJSON(fe.getJson());
}
```

> The `DatatypeConverter` is located under `package javax.xml.bind;`

The problem is occurs when i try to make a thumbnail of this tempFile. The part of code where i try to make a thumbnail:

```
private static String compressFileAndGetFilenameWithExt(File originalFile, int height, String filename, String fileExt) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder newFileName = new StringBuilder(filename)
                    .append("_")
                    .append(height)
                    .append(fileExt);
    File compressedFile = new File(filesLocation + newFileName.toString());
    Thumbnails.Builder<File> builder = Thumbnails.of(originalFile);
    builder = builder.height(height);
    builder.toFile(compressedFile);
    return newFileName.toString();
}
```

I get **IIOException occurred : Error reading PNG metadata** in this line of code: `builder.toFile(compressedFile);`

Can someone explain and help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of bag. This is because i don't configure headers to take file

Comment: Please, if you can, leave the piece of code for us.